# TypeError: DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions is not a function - Error in Angular js datatables

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I have created code for binding the datatable. I don't know what have to do for this? How to fix this issue.Any suggestions welcome.

```
app.controller('ImporatanceTypeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', 'httpService', '$modal', '$log', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $state, httpService, $modal, $log, $stateParams, DTOptionsBuilder, $http) {
 $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
   .withDOM(
          "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
          "<SSS<'col-sm-5'l><'col-sm-7'p>>"); 

//My Function Codes Here..

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little problem on your dependency injection. Your code should look like this:

```
app.controller('ImporatanceTypeCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'httpService', '$modal', '$log', '$stateParams', 'DTOptionsBuilder', '$http', function ($scope, $state, httpService, $modal, $log, $stateParams, DTOptionsBuilder, $http) {
```

Angularjs docs on dependency injection: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di